# how to calculate percentile in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of numbers, and I want below each number to have the percentile of that number (compared to the other numbers in the row). I tried to use =RANK.EQ but that didn't quite work. (since I think I can only use a range over a column instead of a row?)

EDIT: I am looking to map a number x to p(x) where p(x) is the percentage of y's that fall below x in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed all your data is in column A then you can get the percentile of A1 with `=A1/SUM(A:A)`

Same can be done for Rows by replacing `A:A` with the given Row number of the values, for example `2:2`

Answer (score 0):

Let row 1 be your numbers (A1:Z1).
For A2, use =Percentrank($A1:$Z1,A1). Drag formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `y`s but for:

> the percentage of y's that fall below x in that row

suggest in A2 and copied across to suit:

```
=1-RANK(A1,$A1:$Z1)/COUNT($A1:$Z1)
```

where the row with `x`s is assumed to be Row1 and the row length ColumnsA:Z.